# (Three.js) Как создать сферу с градиентовой заливкой?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

В моём коде ничего не работает, что касается света, следовательно я не могу сделать тень для своей модели планеты. Я думаю, что можно было бы на месте сферы с текстурой создать ещё одну сферу чуть побольше, которая имела бы градиентовую заливку чёрного цвета и прозрачного цвета, но нигде не могу найти эту информацию. Как это можно сделать правильно?

```
window.onload = () => {
    const
        canvas = document.getElementById('canv')

    canvas.width  = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true})
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000)
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true

    const
        scene  = new THREE.Scene() // Заносим сцену
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000) // Заносим камеру (угол обзора, пропорции, видимость от и до)
        camera.position.z = 30
        camera.position.x = 30
        camera.position.y = 32

    //const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, canvas )

    const
        light = new THREE.SpotLight()
        light.position.set(80, 0, 0)
        light.castShadow = true
        scene.add(light)

    const
        texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('model/texture.jpg')
        texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
        texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
        texture.repeat.set(6, 6)

        material   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture})
        geometry   = new THREE.SphereGeometry(48, 100, 100)
        mesh       = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

    mesh.receiveShadow = true
    scene.add(mesh)
    
    const
        outlineMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0d0d0d, side: THREE.BackSide } )
        outlineMesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, outlineMaterial )

    outlineMesh.position = mesh.position
    outlineMesh.scale.multiplyScalar(1.005)
    scene.add( outlineMesh )

    const rendering = () => {
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.0001
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(rendering)
    }
    camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)
    rendering()
}
```

[image: Результат на выходе]

Comment: https://github.com/mattdesl/xmas

Comment: "_В моём коде ничего не работает_" - хорошо бы увидеть код, чтобы понять, что в нем не так. Возможно используется MeshBasicMaterial, вместо MeshLambertMaterial, или MeshPhongMaterial, или MeshStandardMaterial. Но давать советы, не видя кода - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, проблема в том что у вас не работает освещение, или в том что вы не знаете как создать сферу с градиентом. Это два принципиально разных вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы объекты затенялись, необходимо использовать материалы, отличные от `MeshBasicMaterial` и `MeshNormalMaterial`, так как эти два материала никак не реагируют на наличие источников освещения в сцене.
Материалы, реагирующие на свет: MeshLambertMaterial, MeshPhongMaterial, MeshStandardMaterial. Описание свойств данных материалов можно найти в справке.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canv"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "http://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let canvas = document.getElementById('canv')

canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
  antialias: true
})
//renderer.setClearColor(0x000000)
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true

let scene = new THREE.Scene() // Заносим сцену
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000) // Заносим камеру (угол обзора, пропорции, видимость от и до)
camera.position.set(30, 30, 20).setLength(100);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement )

let light = new THREE.SpotLight()
light.position.set(200, 0, 0)
light.castShadow = true
scene.add(light)

let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg')
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
texture.repeat.set(6, 6)

let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  map: texture
})
let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(48, 100, 100)
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

mesh.receiveShadow = true
scene.add(mesh)

let outlineMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xd0d0d0,
    side: THREE.BackSide
  })
let outlineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, outlineMaterial)

outlineMesh.position.copy(mesh.position);
outlineMesh.scale.setScalar(1.005)
scene.add(outlineMesh)

const rendering = () => {
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.0001
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  requestAnimationFrame(rendering)
}
//camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0)
rendering()
</script>
```

PS Возможно, имеет смысл использовать DirectionalLight вместо SpotLight.

Comment: Да, освещение действительно отразилось на моей планете благодаря изменению типа для материала. Огромнейшее вам спасибо! Ваш ответ будет отмечен, как найлучший!

Comment: @Endivine Пожалуйста. Рад помочь. :)